# identify yAxis tick interval

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to display total income per quarter (in thousands of pounds) for a variety of departments.

Sometimes the income for the department is quite small. in this case, the y axis values contains 2 decimal places

Sometimes the income is larger and the y axis values contain 1 decimal place

And occasionally, the value are very large and the y axis values do not contain any decimal places

[Fiddle to demonstrate different formatting](https://jsfiddle.net/YaskinForrit/q013zvxj/)

The problem I have is that the current formatting of the y axis looks wrong.

I need to set the number of decimal places on the y axis values based on the tick interval: -
small values (i.e. 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1 etc) need to be formatted to 2 decimal places.
larger values (i.e. 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 etc) need to be formatted to 1 decimal place.
very large values (i.e. 80, 90, 100, 110 etc) need no decimal places.

The actual values can be up to 3 decimal places (e.g. 0.306, 0.518 (small) 1.429, 1.806 (larger) 102.429, 160.806(very large))

My code builds up a script string and then uses ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to run the script.

I have tried to set the number of decimal places based on the values

```
Dim yAxisValue as Double= 0
Dim numberOfDP as Integer = 0
...
While reader.Read
    If yAxisValue < reader.Item("YAxisValues").ToString Then
        yAxisValue = reader.Item("YAxisValues").ToString
        If Val(yAxisValue) < 1 Then
          numberOfDP = 2
        ElseIf Val(yAxisValue) < 10 Then
          numberOfDP = 1
        End If
    End If
End While

MyScript = MyScript & "yAxis: {" & vbCrLf
MyScript = MyScript & "labels: {" & vbCrLf
MyScript = MyScript & "style: {color: 'black'," & vbCrLf
MyScript = MyScript & "'fontSize': '11pt'}," & vbCrLf
MyScript = MyScript & "format: '{value:. & numberOfDP & f}'" & vbCrLf
MyScript = MyScript & "}" & vbCrLf
MyScript = MyScript & "}" & vbCrLf
```

But I would rather base the formatting on the actual tick interval.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`, but in Highcharts you can set `yAxis.labels.formatter` and determine there how many decimals should be displayed, for example:

```
function formatter () {
  var dec = this.axis.tickInterval > 1 ? 0 : (this.axis.tickInterval > 0.1 ? 1 : 2);
  return this.value.toFixed(dec);
}
```

Now just use in yAxis options that:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: formatter
  }
},
```

And live demo for you: https://jsfiddle.net/4y8n33ob/

Comment: Thanks for this it works a treat. I have had to tweak it slightly due to some obscure tick intervals but without your answer, I would have been lost

Comment: Of course, it was just an idea. tickIntervals like `0.1` vs `1` etc. should be changed to meet your requirement :)